Paste part of what is in clipboard
I have an Excel file that I copy data to, however I have one column more in the source file than what I need in the target file.
I tried to split the data in the clipboard to lines, then remove the last item in the line then rebuild the string in the clipboard without the extra column but the pasting it does not work.
I get a 1004 error with the description "Can't paste data" or something similar.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    
    strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1)
    rader = Split(strPaste, vbNewLine)


    For i = 0 To UBound(rader)
        If rader(i) <> "" Then rader(i) = Left(rader(i), InStrRev(rader(i), vbTab) - 1)
    Next i
    strPaste = Join(rader, vbNewLine)
    DataObj.SetText strPaste
    DataObj.PutInClipboard
    
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    LRRS = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LRRS).Select
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LRRS).PasteSpecial xlValues

I have tried different methods of paste, with or without selecting first and Worksheet.Paste but I believe the rebuilding of the string does not create what Excel expects to paste in a cell range.
I have also tried to transpose paste the array but I fail with that too.
Is there any method I can either paste the array or change the copied contents so that I can paste it?

"I have one column more in the source file than what I need in the target file." - then don't copy that column in the first place. Also no need to use Paste - especially as you are using .PasteSpecial xlValues - just assign the source range value to the target range value .
As for "or something similar." - always paste the full wording of error messages to maximise your chances of getting a meaningful solution

What is the source of the data? Is it from another Excel, or a file, or grabbing some information from a Web page? There should be better ways to get the data into Excel than to tinker with the Clipboard.

Have you tried PasteSpecial xlPasteAll ?

Do you try pasting that string in a cell? As asked above, where from the clipboard content is loaded? At least, did you check if strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1) returns what you need? If so, why using the clipboard again? You can simple use wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LRRS).Value = strPaste. Then, wouldn't it be better to paste each array line on a separate cell? I mean,  using wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LRRS).Resize(Ubound(rader) + 1, 1).value = Application.Transpose(rader). Of course, using rader after removing the last element of each row...

@CHill60 I want to make it easier by just pressing CTRL+A, CTRL+C. Remembering to remove a column has been proven to not work. Sure the full wording is "Det går inte att klistra in data". Did that help you?

@FunThomas it originates from another Excel sheet which is open in Citrix, because of this they are not in the same instance of Excel. Because of this the easiest solution I have found is to copy it and have a macro on the other sheet detect that I have copied and start this process above. Get text(1) does give me what I want, but it also gives me the last column that I don't want. On the target file there is a formula in that column that will get destroyed if I paste values there. Will try the suggestion tomorrow at work.

@Blackcat no, don't want the formatting. But I guess the text should be without formatting since it has gone through an array. I can try it tomorrow.

And just to clear some confusion. The code works fine if I remove the loop part and the putting the string back in the clipboard. So if I just copy the correct columns and just paste it then it works as expected. Now I just want to try to make sure I don't screw up my target sheet with a column I don't need.

What does "it originates from another Excel sheet which is open in Citrix" mean? Is it a range? If yes, it is possible to extract the range from clipboard. And use it. Place its value in an array, paste it, returning its address etc. If necessary, I can post such a piece of code. But you did not answer anything related to my above comment...

@FaneDuru I said I will try it tomorrow. Last sentence. Having an Excel workbook in Citrix is kind of like having a second computer that runs the Excel that you can see and use on your computer but with the added benefit that you can copy from one to the other. Excel application does not run on my computer but on a server far away, and then on my own PC I have a local copy of Excel. The reason this sheet opens on the server/Citrix is because I export the file from an application running on the server.

@FaneDuru Your method with resize and transpose works. It just needs a text to columns after that is done. Feel free to post it as an answer.

OK, I will post a piece of code. I think it is not need to waste time with iteration. I have in mind finding the last column after TextToColumns and clear its content... It is my first day at the office after vacation and I am rather busy. When I will found some availability I will edit the answer and place another one able to deal with ClipBoard using API and extract the range itself. Then, put it in an array and drop the array content. Theoretically, it should be very fast even for large ranges...

Please, test the next updated code:
Sub CopyFromClipboard_Arrays()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rader, strPaste As String, LRRS As Long
    Dim arrLine, finArr, i As Long, j As Long, colsNo As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    
    strPaste = DataObj.getText(1)
    rader = Split(strPaste, vbNewLine)
    colsNo = UBound(Split(rader(0), vbTab))   'determine the necessary number of columns (rader is 0 based)
    
    ReDim finArr(1 To UBound(rader) + 1, 1 To colsNo) 'ReDim the final 2D array with the necessary rows/columns
    For i = 0 To UBound(rader)                'iterate between rader elements
        arrLine = Split(rader(i), vbTab)      'place the rader element in another array by splitting on vbTab
        For j = 0 To UBound(arrLine) - 1      'load the final array row (minus the last column)
            finArr(i + 1, j + 1) = arrLine(j)
        Next j
    Next i
    LRRS = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1 'last row on A:A
        
    'drop the processed array, at once:
    ws.Range("A" & LRRS).Resize(UBound(finArr), UBound(finArr, 2)).Value = finArr
    
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

When (If) I will have some availability I will edit the answer and I place another piece of code (more complex) able to extract the range object from clipboard. Then place it in an array and drop its content.
Edited:
Please, try the next more elaborate code able to extract the range from ClipBoard, place it in an array and drop its content where you need:

Place the next API declarations on top of a standard module (in the declarations area). For 64bit installations:

Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal lngFormat As Long) As LongPtr 'modificat din Long in Any
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpString1 As Any, ByVal lpString2 As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardFormatNameA Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumClipboardFormats Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long



Please copy the next code in the same standard module:

Sub CopyFromClipboardAPI() 'extract the range from ClipBoard...
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rader, LRRS As Long
   
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim dataHwnd As LongPtr                 'pointer to clipboard data
    Dim intOffset As Integer                'for parsing clipboard data
    Dim strClipData As String               'clipboard data
    Dim strGetClipRange As String           'return range address (wb and ws)
    Dim rngFormatID As Long                 'id number for link format (Range)
    Const intMaxSize As Integer = 256       'limit for r1c1 to a1 conversion

    rngFormatID = getRangeFormatID("Link")   'extracting the id number for "link" format (Range)
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then GoTo safeExit
    dataHwnd = GetClipboardData(rngFormatID) 'pointer to clipboard data
    If dataHwnd = CLngPtr(0) Then GoTo safeExit 'could not allocate memory
    dataHwnd = GlobalLock(dataHwnd)         'lock clipboard memory, so we can reference
    If IsNull(dataHwnd) Then GoTo safeExit  'could not lock clipboard memory
    
    intOffset = 0                           'start parsing data
    strClipData = space$(intMaxSize)        'initialize string
    Call lstrcpy(strClipData, dataHwnd + intOffset)        'copy pointer to string
    If strClipData = space$(intMaxSize) Then GoTo safeExit 'not excel range on clipboard
    strClipData = Mid(strClipData, 1, InStr(1, strClipData, Chr$(0), 0) - 1) 'trim null character
    If strClipData <> "Excel" Then GoTo safeExit           'not excel range on clipboard
    
    intOffset = intOffset + 1 + Len(strClipData)           'next offset
    strClipData = space$(intMaxSize)                       'reset string
    Call lstrcpy(strClipData, dataHwnd + intOffset)        'book and sheet next
    strClipData = Mid(strClipData, 1, InStr(1, strClipData, Chr$(0), 0) - 1) 'trim null character
    strGetClipRange = "'" & strClipData & "'!"             'get workbookbook and sheet
    intOffset = intOffset + 1 + Len(strClipData)    'next offset
    strClipData = space$(intMaxSize)                'initialize string
    Call lstrcpy(strClipData, dataHwnd + intOffset) 'range next
    strClipData = Mid(strClipData, 1, InStr(1, strClipData, Chr$(0), 0) - 1) 'trim null character
    strGetClipRange = strGetClipRange & strClipData 'add range to extracted string (xlR1C1 style)

    strGetClipRange = Application.ConvertFormula(strGetClipRange, xlR1C1, xlA1) 'convert the range style
    
    Dim ClipBRange As Range
    Set ClipBRange = Range(strGetClipRange)          'range in a1 style
    
    Call GlobalUnlock(dataHwnd) 'unlock clipboard memory
    Call CloseClipboard         'close ClipBoard
    
    rader = ClipBRange.Value    'place the range in a 2D array
    
    LRRS = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1 'first empty row on A:A
    ws.Range("A" & LRRS).Resize(UBound(rader), UBound(rader, 2) - 1).Value = rader 'UBound(rader, 2) -1 to except
                                                                                   'copying the last column
    MsgBox "Ready..."
    Exit Sub 'if all went well...
safeExit:
    Call GlobalUnlock(dataHwnd)    'unlock clipboard memory
    Call CloseClipboard            'close ClipBoard
End Sub

Function getRangeFormatID(strFormatName As String) As Long 'it looks that for a range the ID is not a constant...
    Dim FormatId As Long, retFormat As String, formatLength As Integer
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then Exit Function   'could not open clipboard
    formatLength = Len(strFormatName) + 30        'we only need a couple extra to make sure there isn't more
    FormatId = 0 'initialized at zero
    Do
        retFormat = space(formatLength)           'initialize string
        GetClipboardFormatNameA FormatId, retFormat, formatLength 'get the id name
        retFormat = Trim(retFormat)               'trim spaces
        If retFormat <> "" Then                   'if some string remained
            retFormat = left(retFormat, Len(retFormat) - 1) 'get rid of terminal character
            'Debug.Print retFormat, FormatId: 'Stop
            If retFormat = strFormatName Then     'if it matches strFormatName
                getRangeFormatID = FormatId           'return the correspondent id number
                Exit Do                           'exit Loop
            End If
        End If
        FormatId = EnumClipboardFormats(FormatId) 'get the next id number
    Loop Until FormatId = 0                       'exit the loop after last id number
    Call CloseClipboard                           'close clipboard
End Function

Run the code and see how fast it is. Of course, if the ClipBoard contains an Excel Range. And this range is in a workbook having a path (even from network) understandable by computer where the code runs...
The above API declarations are for 64bit installations. It can be easily adapted to work for both cases.
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

I went on holiday a few hours ago. I will give it a try if I have time. The first method by glance wont work since it will overwrite a formula in the target table. That is why I want to remove one column before I paste the data. Second method seems a bit more technical, I won't be able to test it for a week at least. But I will try it when I get home again and have time.

@Andreas Firstly, happy vacation! 1. Does the overwriting issue involve already existing data after the space necessary to drop the content of split clipboard content? So, do you know how many columns must the range form clipBoard have? If so, I think I would be able to adapt the code to process everything in memory and load a second array. Then, drop only one column less. 2. The second method can be easily adapted to drop only the necessary columns. In fact, it will become faster. I played a little with it and it looks that rngFormat is not constant (as I thought)...

@Andreas I extracted it using a function and I thought that all the time it will be the same. I did that when dealing with files copied in clipBoard, embedded objects in the sheet etc. and it was all the time the same. Of course, I can adapt the code to use that function each time.

@Andreas Updated both versions to return in sheet excepting the last column... No any rush to test it. You will do it when you will have availability. Have a nice holiday!
